In Thunderbird, sender "name" shows as "me" when forwarding emails
When I receive emails at an address that I also send emails with (via SMTP), Thunderbird will show the name as "Me". Even though I do not have that email in my contact book.
This is a problem when you forward emails to yourself, and require the name to know the email address of who is contacting you.
Screenshot
This is an incoming email, I forwarded to myself. Thunderbird replaces the sender's name with "Me".

Context
I send emails with AWS SES via SMTP; however, to receive emails, I must forward emails to another account. AWS SES only allows you to forward emails from accounts that you own. So, this requires me to forward emails from myself to another email I own (not represented), and put the sender's name and email BOTH in the name field.
Annoyingly, Thunderbird always shows this address as "Me" regardless of whether I have my email in my address book as a contact. Thunderbird does this because of your existing SMTP configuration.

Solution 1
Save your email in your address book. Set a display name, and check the box which says "Prefer display name over message header":

This will display as First Last and will omit the email address.
Solution 2
If for some reason, you need to have the email address displayed, instead of the above, do the following:

Tools -> Account Settings
Make sure the Field Your Name is not empty
Next, click on  Manage Identities ... then on Add...
Fill out the fields of Your Name (with something else in respect to your primary Identity)  and of Email address

This will set the email header for the sender as Your Name <email@address> according to the identity you choose when sending the email, and the Me should disappear.

Thanks for the ideas, but this misses the problem I'm trying to solve. Your solutions involve manually setting a name on this email. I don't want this. I forward mail from this address, so I want the sender's "name" to always be respected because it's different for each email.

Turns out, there is a configuration that fixes this problem.
mail.showCondensedAddresses should be changed to false. This disables Thunderbird automatically replacing the sender's name with "Me".
That option has the side effect of showing your contacts as "Name " instead of just "Name".
Screenshots
Before:

After:

Note: Original sender's email address is blurred. My email forwarding automatically adds "at EMAIL_ADDRESS" to the end of the sender's name, this is an unusual setup.
Steps to update this config

Access Config Editor:

Click on the menu button (three horizontal lines) in the top right corner.
Select Settings.
Click on the General tab.
Click the Config Editor... button.


Bypass Warning:

If prompted with a warning message, click I accept the risk! to proceed.


Search for the Configuration:

In the search bar at the top, type mail.showCondensedAddresses


Modify the Configuration:

Locate the mail.showCondensedAddresses entry in the list.
Double-click on it to change its value from true to false.



